# How to backup the installed application's .apk file?

Tags: android, backup, apk

How to take backup the installed application's .apk file in device or emulator which we're using by programmatically. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**I am sure this kind of programming not possible (May be possible for rooted phone)**, because just consider if this is possible then paid application's Apk can easily available in market in free of charge, so if this is the case then what does it mean to develop paid android application?

Even though, it is possible then i am really interested to learn this programming snippets.

Comment: It is really possible. There are tools available even in android market. Backup Utilities... Such as Rom Manager perform copying the apks to SD card or external storage... It is possible.

Comment: @AndroidKid : I didn't need any application to take backup of installed applications. I want to create an own application by programmatically. So that i need little idea for to do that.

Comment: I was telling @PM - Paresh Mayani that it is possible.. I am not sure how the coding is done.. As far as i know, To read the apks you need elevated privileges(root?).. Maybe..

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the Android OS is a Linux OS.
If you have root access to your device, you can copy the protected files and do whatever you want with them.

The APK files are located in the /data folder.